# How to filter entities by many relationship count using SUBQUERY in Core Data

Tags: database, sqlite, core-data

I would like to get a list of cities that have location with more than 3 checkins.

city -> locations -> checkins

It seems I tried every possible subquery and I keep getting obscure errors. Would really appreciate some help.

`"SUBQUERY(locations, $l, $l.checkins.@count > 3).@count != 0"`

> 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle $l.checkins.@count'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate parser seems to recognise both the KVC aggregate functions, like `@count` and `@sum`, and the `NSExpression` functions like `count:` - I think you can use the latter, like this:

```
"SUBQUERY(locations, $l, count:($l.checkins) > 3).@count != 0"
```